# Convert output of split from list to integer

Tags: python

I want to to split a `readline` input from a text file named `data.txt` in Python:

```
0.97681 0.10723 0.64385 0.29556 1
```

The goal is to obtain the data as its original type (i.e. `int` or `float`)
as following code:

```
with open("data.txt", mode="r") as file:
   stream = file.readline()
   stream_split = stream.split()
   x = [float(e) for e in stream_split]
```

I expected this operation would turn the output of split,
`['0.97681','0.10723', '0.64385', '0.29556','1']`  into
`[0.97681, 0.10723, 0.64385, 0.29556, 1]`.

But my compiler give me an `ValueError`, which really confused me.

Comment: Please do not post images of your code

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: What *integer* were you expecting 0.97681 to be converted to?  These are floats, not ints.

Comment: Please don't post photos of your data (and certainly not links to photos). This is not accessible to everyone and is inaccessible to search. Additionally, the question makes no sense if those links break. Consider editing the question to copy and paste everything we need to know into the body of the question.

Comment: Use `float()` instead of `int()`

Comment: you can convert floats to integers with `int(my_float)`.

Comment: Sorry for those image, Im tried to correct them now

Comment: Thank you guys, it work after I change the data type to float

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that your issue is already resolved, i'll add my code here anyways:

**Data**

```
0.97 0.10  0.6 1
0.2  0.63 0.7 1
```

**Code**

```py
with open ("data.txt", mode="r") as file:
    
    # Contains all lines of the file
    stream = file.readlines()
    print(stream)

    # All lines of the file splited
    parts = [s.split() for s in stream]
    print(parts)

    # Converting strings to float
    parts_converted = [[float(y) for y in s] for s in parts]
    print(parts_converted)

    # If you want to have everything in one flat list
    flat_parts = [item for sublist in parts_converted for item in sublist]
    print(flat_parts)
```

**Output**

```
['0.97 0.10  0.6 1\n', '0.2  0.63 0.7 1']
[['0.97', '0.10', '0.6', '1'], ['0.2', '0.63', '0.7', '1']]
[[0.97, 0.1, 0.6, 1.0], [0.2, 0.63, 0.7, 1.0]]
[0.97, 0.1, 0.6, 1.0, 0.2, 0.63, 0.7, 1.0]
```

The issue was that you were trying to convert a floating point number using `int()` instead of `float()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the you have the dictionary of strings as, `x= ['0.97681','0.10723', '0.64385', '0.29556','1']`, you can just do `x=[float(e) for e in stream_split]`. What you were doing had nothing wrong with the method. However, 0.64385 is a float, not an integer.

Comment: What's wrong with using a list comprehension? The error was simply using `int` instead of `float`.

Comment: Barmar, there was nothing wrong, I will edit my answer to reflect that.